# Haxe java.lang.Object Equivalent

Tags: class, inheritance, haxe

Haxe allows class inheritance hierarchies

```
class Honda extends Car {
...
}
```

is there a common inheritance hierarchy root for all objects?  I have a generic container class that could contain any object and I want to be able to declare

```
var _contents:Object; //Any class instance in _contents
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also use `{}` as a type, which will accept class instances as well as anonymous objects :

```
var _contents:{};
```

We also have `Dynamic`, which basically means "anything" (not only objects, but also primitives like `Bool`, `Int`, etc).

If your class is a generic container, you may want to type its content, though, using type parameters:

```
class Container<T> {
  var _contents:T;
  public function new(contents:T):Void {
    _contents = contents;
  }
}
```

And then:

```
var arrayContainer = new Container([]);
var stuffContainer = new Container({foo:"bar"});
var classContainer = new Container( new Stuff() );
```

Answer (score 1):

The inheritance root for classes is `Class<T>` so the following should work:

```
var _contents:Class<T>;
```

However, to store an `Enum`, you would have to use `Enum<T>` instead.

From the [manual](http://haxe.org/manual/types-class-instance.html):

> There is a special type in Haxe which is compatible with all classes:
>
> **Define: `Class<T>`**
>
> This type is compatible with all class types which means that all classes (not their instances) can be assigned to it. At compile-time, `Class<T>` is the common base type of all class types. However, this relation is not reflected in generated code.
>
> This type is useful when an API requires a value to be **a** class, but not a specific one. This applies to several methods of the [Haxe reflection API](http://haxe.org/manual/std-reflection.html).